# C program compilation error: undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc

I am unable to compile the following simple C code and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
     double result;
     result = cos(0.5);
     printf("asin(0.5) is %f\n", result);
     return 0;
}
```

The error message I receive after I try to compile is -

```
In function 

'main':
test.c:(.text+0xlc): undefined reference to 'cos'
collect2: ld

 returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Btw, I hope you noticed that you're calculating a cosine, and saying the result is the arc-sine, which are not the same thing.

Comment: This is actually a linker error rather than a compiler error. That is made clear because the error is coming from `ld`, the linker. Invariably the reason is a missing import library.

Answer (score 14):

You need to link with the math library (`-lm`).

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o test test.c -lm
```

See this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/fp/libm.html).

Answer (score 0):

In general whenever you get undefined reference error it's due to the compiler is not able to find your function definition. So it may be your function ( and you have not typed the spelling of function correctly so you will get this error ) or may be built-in function like you have encountered in this case. 
to explore there are various library and their linking are necessary at the time of compilation
whenever you use math function use `-lm` ( l stands for link and m is for math )
in pthread built-in functions use `-lpthread`
and so on ...
In this case indeed use -lm

```
gcc -lm test.c
```

will be able to compile your program .